# How to create the xml document in C#.net

Tags: c#

This is my xml document,i need to create this xml document in c#.net

```
<RoleHierarchyDetails xmlns="http://cts.com/rhms/RoleHierarchyEvent">
            <RoleHierarchyDetail>
                  <AssociateID></AssociateID>
                  <UserName>Sandeep Mutha</UserName>
                  <RoleId>R_ID_0018</RoleId>
                  <RoleName>SBU2 Head</RoleName>
                  <PortfolioName>AXA SWISS</PortfolioName>
                  <PortfolioType>SBU2</PortfolioType>
                  <PortfolioId>222</PortfolioId>
                  <HierarchyId>HT_ID_001</HierarchyId>
                  <HierarchyName>BU Hierarchy</HierarchyName>
                  <AlternatePortfolioId></AlternatePortfolioId>
                  <AlternateNodeName></AlternateNodeName>
                  <ActiveFlag>1</ActiveFlag>
            </RoleHierarchyDetail>
      </RoleHierarchyDetails>
```

I need ur help
Thanks in advance

Comment: do u want to creat this type of xml document by running C#.net.???

Answer (score 4):

You want the [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class:

```
string xmlString = 
@"<RoleHierarchyDetails xmlns=""http://cts.com/rhms/RoleHierarchyEvent"">
    <RoleHierarchyDetail>
        <AssociateID></AssociateID>
        <UserName>Sandeep Mutha</UserName>
        <RoleId>R_ID_0018</RoleId>
        <RoleName>SBU2 Head</RoleName>
        <PortfolioName>AXA SWISS</PortfolioName>
        <PortfolioType>SBU2</PortfolioType>
        <PortfolioId>222</PortfolioId>
        <HierarchyId>HT_ID_001</HierarchyId>
        <HierarchyName>BU Hierarchy</HierarchyName>
        <AlternatePortfolioId></AlternatePortfolioId>
        <AlternateNodeName></AlternateNodeName>
        <ActiveFlag>1</ActiveFlag>
    </RoleHierarchyDetail>
</RoleHierarchyDetails>";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
return doc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at LINQ to XML via [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) or using [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kza7w4k%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

You should use [XML Serialization](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=173)

Your question is soooo basic. Use google before asking

Comment: I think he never stated he has any kind of object to serialize. I understand he wants to know about System.Xml or LINQ to XML. Спокойнее :-)